# how to identify two different jsp page buttons in action class?how to write the condition, based on jsp page View button and view All Button?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts-1

File name is ScanorAttach.jsp- this file contains view All button. note- i am importing results.jsp.

```
<c:if test="${not empty scanForm.results1 || not empty scanForm.results2}">
<input type="button" value="View All"  class="button float-right" onclick="showDocuments('')"/>

</c:if>

<tr>
<td>
 <c:import url="/jsp/common/scan/results.jsp"/></td>
</tr>
```

results.jsp  - this file contains view button

```
 <c:forEach var="result" items="${scanForm.results1}" varStatus="status">
                            <tr class="${zebra}">
                                <td>${result.documentName}</td>
                                <c:if test="${empty scanForm.documentId && loginuser.role.roleDesc eq 'Admin'}">
                                    <td>${result.screenName}</td>
                                </c:if>
                                <td>
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${empty scanForm.documentId && loginuser.role.roleDesc eq 'Admin'}">
                                            <img src="${path}/images/edit.png" title="Edit" onclick="editDocument('${result.id}');"/>
                                            <img src="${path}/images/trash.png" title="Delete" onclick="removeDocument('${result.documentName}', '${result.id}');"/>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <c:if test="${not (roleDuty.viewAccountingScanAttach
                                                              && (scanForm.screenName eq 'INVOICE' || scanForm.screenName eq 'AR BATCH'))}">
                                                  <img src="${path}/images/icons/scanner.png" title="Scan" onclick="showComment('${result.documentName}', 'Scan');"/>
                                                  <img src="${path}/images/icons/attach.png" title="Attach" onclick="showComment('${result.documentName}', 'Attach');"/>
                                            </c:if>
                                        <img src="${path}/images/icons/preview.png" title="View" onclick="showDocuments('${result.documentName}')"/> 
                                            <c:if test="${result.uploadCount > 0}">
                                                <span class="red-90" style="vertical-align: super">
                                                    (${result.uploadCount})
                                                </span>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </c:forEach>
```

For example i have 2 document booking and Photos. if i click view(booking) button particular document(booking only) is viewed. if i click view all button all files(booking and photos) should be displayed. 
file name -documents.jsp

```
<div class="results-container">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="display-table" id="filelist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('documentName')">Document Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('fileName')">File Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('fileSize')">File Size</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('operation')">Operation</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('operationDate')">Operation Date</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('status')">Status</a></th>
            <th><a href="javascript:doSort('comment')">Comments</a></th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:set var="zebra" value="odd"/>
        <c:forEach var="result" items="${scanForm.results}" varStatus="status">
            <tr class="${zebra}">
                <td>${result.documentName}</td>
                <td>${result.fileName}</td>
                <td>${result.fileSize}</td>
                <td>${result.operation}</td>
                <td>${result.operationDate}</td>
                <td class="receivedMasterStatus${status.index}">${result.status}</td>
                <td>${str:splitter(result.comments, 75, '<br/>')}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="${path}/images/icons/preview.png"
                          title="View" onclick="viewDocument('${result.fileName}', '${result.fileLocation}/${result.fileName}')"/>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${roleDuty.deleteAttachedDocuments eq 'true' && not empty results3}">
                           <img src="${path}/images/trash.png"
                                 title="Delete" onclick="deleteDocumentSop('${result.id}', '${result.fileName}', '${result.documentName}')"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>                                
                            <c:if test="${roleDuty.deleteAttachedDocuments eq 'true'}">
                                    <img src="${path}/images/trash.png"
                                     title="Delete" onclick="deleteDocument('${result.id}', '${result.fileName}', '${result.documentName}')"/>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Action Class name- ScanAction.jsp

```
 public ActionForward showDocuments(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ScanForm scanForm = (ScanForm) form;
    if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(scanForm.getScreenName())) {
        List<ResultModel> results = new ScanDAO().getDocuments(scanForm.getScreenName(), scanForm.getDocumentName(), scanForm.getDocumentId());
        scanForm.setResults(results);
    }
    request.setAttribute("results3", request.getSession().getAttribute("results3"));
    return mapping.findForward(DOCUMENTS);
}

public ActionForward deleteDocument(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ScanForm scanForm = (ScanForm) form;
    DocumentStoreLogDAO documentDAO = new DocumentStoreLogDAO();
    DocumentStoreLog document = documentDAO.findById(scanForm.getId());
    File file = new File(document.getFileLocation(), document.getFileName());
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    request.setAttribute("message", document.getFileName() + " is deleted successfully");
    documentDAO.delete(document);
  //   scanForm.setDocumentName(""); here i want to write condition and also how to differentiate view and View All Button. 
    return showDocuments(mapping, form, request, response);
}
```

the list is not properly working.Booking contains 2 files. photos contains 3 files.if i delete 1 file in booking , after deleting only one file is shown. in my project it shows all files ( photos files also ) .i think you are understood. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
if(request.getParameter("viewAll.x") != null){ <br>

}else if(request.getParameter("view.x") != null){ <br>

}
```

In action class you can check if user clicked on each button or not.

Comment: I was having the same problem to detect which button has ween submitted when there are more than one button inside same form. This solved the problem. Thumbs up